# Python 3 Tkinter Freezing Problem in PyCharm

Tags: python, user-interface, tkinter

How do I update my code so that the Tkinter GUI doesn't just freeze?

I'm having some problems with building a GUI using Tkinter in PyCharm as it freezes after 5-10 seconds. I'm trying to build a basic GUI which can then communicate with an Arduino (where different clicks send different signals to the Arduino's serial monitor).

I've had a good hunt around the topic and I'm struggling to understand what is causing the problem (I feel it must be related to the structure of my code and Tkinter's interaction with mainloop()). I apologise if it is something really basic as I've only just begun to learn to code!

Really appreciate any help or pointers! :D

Thank you!!

```
from tkinter import *
import serial
import time

window = Tk()

window.title("Dashboard")
window.geometry('1300x700')

ser = serial.Serial('COM3', 9600)

def aa():
    ser.write(b'!')

def ab():
    ser.write(b'a')

btn = Button(window, text="0", command=aa)
btn.grid(column=0, row=0)
btn = Button(window, text="1", command=ab)
btn.grid(column=1, row=0)

window.mainloop()
```

Comment: Unfortunately your code doesn't show the culprit. Have you ever heard about [dictionaries](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html#dictionaries)? Take the tour [Python Dictionary Quick Guide](https://www.pythonforbeginners.com/dictionary/python-dictionary-quick-guide)

Comment: By default, the `Serial.write()` method will block forever until the data is sent, so that may be causing the hang-up. You can limit the amount of time it will wait by specifying a `timeout=` value (in seconds) when you create the instance.